# Java reading text lines without line separators

Tags: java, file

For processing a searchlog file I'm writing a Java class that should read and handle the file content line by line.

The Text in the Logfile looks like the following

```
[Integer User ID] [Queury] [Date: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS] [optional url]
```

I tried using a scanner and reading the lines with nextLine(), but this reads the whole file as one line. Any idea how I can ensure to only get one line at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just grab the entire file as you have it, and then split the data:

```
for ( String line : "the entire file".split( System.getProperty("line.separator") )
{
     System.out.println( line );
}
```

As a side note: `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is the universal new line character.

An alternative method:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "absolute file path" ) );

String line;

while ( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null)
{
     System.out.println( line );
}
```

Comment: Log files are usually quite big to load into memory at once. Not only that, but the .split will cause to allocate twice as much!

Comment: Pretty much what Fermin Silva said, we're talking about 212mb txt files here

Comment: @Rickyfox i added a second method using bufferedReader.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `BufferedReader` instead of `Scanner`. `BufferedReader` is tolerant of various different types of line terminator - it's possible that `Scanner` always expects your platform-default line terminator.

Alternatively, use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) which lets you do this really easily, e.g. with [`CharStreams.readLines`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#readLines%28java.lang.Readable%29), potentially specifying a `LineProcessor`.

Comment: If I recall it right I had the same problem when trying bufferedReader, but I'll double-check it

Comment: @Rickyfox: Well if you did, that would suggest you're either not reading the file properly (encoding issues?) or your file has odd line endings. What encoding *is* the file in?